How to make an Outlook Office Add-in appear in Ribbon in Outlook desktop
I am developing an Outlook add-in, and I need assistance to ensure that my custom button appears in the Home tab. Currently, my add-in only shows up in the add-in section when a mail item is selected. My goal is to have a button visible in the Home tab at all times,

you can not manage add-ins yourself outlook will automatically manage it
